# 3次元でプロットができない

Tags: python, matplotlib

ランダムに作り出した点を3次元にプロットしようとしたらエラーを吐き出し、解決できません。
以下がコードです。

```
xs=[]
ys=[]
zs=[]

for _ in range(3):
   
    x=np.random.randn(1)
    y=np.random.randn(1)
    z=np.random.randn(1)
    
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)
    zs.append(z)
    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig=plt.figure()
ax=Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, "o", color="red", ms=4, mew=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
xs,ys,zs
```

次にエラー内容です。

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-3315fc4fb28c> in <module>
     23 fig=plt.figure()
     24 ax=Axes3D(fig)
---> 25 ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, "o", color="red", ms=4, mew=0.5)
     26 
     27 ax.set_xlabel('x')

ValueError: input operand has more dimensions than allowed by the axis remapping
```

Comment: 例えばこの辺のtutorialのどれかを参考にしてみては？ [mplot3d tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)

Comment: 質問のソースに近いのはこちらの記事でしょうか。[【Matplotlib】3D散布図の作成](https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/matplotlib-scatter-plot-3d/)

Comment: Axes3Dのplotメソッドでエラーが出ている、と親切にエラー出力してくれていますので、エラー内容を調べてみればいかがでしょうか。英文で書いてあっても検索すればなにがしか見つかりますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: 初期化を `xs, ys, zs = np.random.randn(3, 3)` に変更しても宜しいかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

質問記事のソースと類似の内容を記述している記事が以下にあり、そちらは正常に動作します。
[【Matplotlib】3D散布図の作成](https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/matplotlib-scatter-plot-3d/)

何が違うかというと、それぞれのデータ作成部分が違うわけです。

確認するには、それぞれのプログラムをスクリプトファイルにしてPythonで実行するのでは無く、Pythonインタプリタを立ち上げて、それぞれのプログラムソースをコピペ実行すると、質問のプログラムはエラーが発生しますがそのために使ったデータは残っていて、内容を調べることが出来ます。

---

質問記事のソースでは、最後の xs,ys,zs の表示結果を見ると、それぞれが1個だけの要素を持つnumpy.ndarrayのリストが、通常のPythonのリストの中に3つ並んでいる。いわばハイブリッドな[3][1]の2次元配列になっています。(内容は見易いように編集してあります)

```
([array([0.37819465]), array([1.18331264]), array([0.30752097])],
 [array([1.04432989]), array([1.86562421]), array([1.20300503])],
 [array([0.00736387]), array([-0.05291031]), array([0.24431243])])
```

対して動作する方のソースでは、同様にデータを x,y,z で表示させると、それぞれは100個の要素を持つ1次元のnumpy.ndarrayのリストになっています。

```
(array([-1.20776617,  0.0755103 ,  0.29309606,  0.81499591, -0.04779708,
       -0.22722229,  0.1407896 ,  1.52444428, -1.1203402 ,  0.30589895,
       途中省略
        1.124391  , -0.49878404,  1.13699793,  0.06535393,  0.3135273 ]),
 array([-0.23766362,  0.34777034,  0.37287076,  1.27270215, -0.03464486,
        1.17946645,  0.88012189, -0.87574693, -1.3405201 ,  0.21947388,
       途中省略
       -0.72929008, -1.47974863,  1.8906365 ,  0.27601246, -0.81644342]),
 array([-0.0088914 , -0.96830462, -0.80176708,  0.14194074,  1.48899668,
       -0.49330629,  0.32355049, -0.57031329,  1.12166974,  0.90732565,
       途中省略
        0.3123933 ,  0.0106583 ,  0.39350928, -1.65329012,  0.76048113]))
```

---

修正方法の1つは、Pythonリストの初期化とか`for`ループを使わず、動作する方の記事のように直接1次元のnumpy.ndarrayのリストを作ってしまうことです。
該当部分のソースは以下の3行にまとめられます。

```
xs=np.random.randn(3)
ys=np.random.randn(3)
zs=np.random.randn(3)
```

結果はこうなります。

```
(array([-0.51921527, -1.51555862,  2.63425821]),
 array([-0.63553749,  1.39414176,  0.70619291]),
 array([-0.24555452, -1.21405485, -2.22118169]))
```

---

もう一つの修正方法は、`for`ループを残すとしたら、初期化とかappendで使うメソッドをnumpyのものに変えることです。
ソースは以下のようになります。

```
xs=np.empty(0)
ys=np.empty(0)
zs=np.empty(0)

for _ in range(3):
   
    x=np.random.randn(1)
    y=np.random.randn(1)
    z=np.random.randn(1)
    
    xs=np.append(xs,x)
    ys=np.append(ys,y)
    zs=np.append(zs,z)
```

作り方は違いますが、結果は上記と同様になります。

```
(array([0.16575579, 0.12194223, 0.95687037]),
 array([-2.24153148,  0.11853497, -0.03863972]),
 array([ 0.14752166,  0.05863792, -1.40674958]))
```

---